# Run a script on systemd service ONLY at shutdown not restart

Tags: linux, shutdown, systemd

```
[Unit]  
Description=test  
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]  
ExecStart=/bin/true  
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/test.sh  
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried a lots of examples, but didn't work. The above example works both restart and shutdown. I want to work ONLY at shutdown.

I don't have server. It is my personal pc. I have Gnu/linux os. Is it possible to run script only at shutdown and not restart?

Comment: How would you distinguish: 1) a plain shutdown, 2) a restart, but the system is axed before its starts again, 3) a shutdown, and the system is manually restarted right after. In other words, why are you trying to make a distinction? To avoid some lengthy shutdown process during a restart?

Comment: I want to wipe some files/logs  when I shutdown my pc. I don't want to wipe files when I restart the pc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test in your script if you are rebooting, halting or powering off the system and decide what to do accordingly.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! systemctl list-jobs | grep -q -e "reboot.target.*start"; then
   printf "Not rebooting\n"
fi
```

In `man systemd.special` you can see all targets.
You may want to pay more attention to:

- shutdown.target
- reboot.target
- halt.target
- poweroff.target

Comment: I think tha you do not understand my problem. My script is very simple, just delete some files. It is working but systemd.service start my script when I reboot and when I shutdown. As i said I want systemd service start my script to delete my files OLNY at SHUTDOWN.

Comment: Mike, the example provided does exactly what you described. You just have to write your `rm` instead of my `printf`. Everytime you are in every shutting process (halt, power-off and reboot) your test.sh will be executed; inside your test.sh you have to check, as provided example, if you are not rebooting in order to execute the actual piece of code you want ONLY when you SHUTDOWN

Comment: It is working but I have a problem. I use the srm command, it takes a long to wipe the files so my script It doesn't finsh and system shutdown. How can I start shutdown systemd service after my script end?

Comment: Pretty much another problem...
You can try with something like this: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/11/28/delayed-shutdown-initscript/

Comment: I solved the problem with this command TimeoutSec=300min. Thank you

Comment: If you fear data being recovered, you can ever crypt your disk and/or use an ssd with active trim.

Comment: I have active trim, on my gnu-linux, the problem with ssd is if wipe files that files can be recovered. I think for better security I have to wipe whole ssd disk.

Comment: Mike, you realize that using srm ages the SSD at a rate 38x faster than regular usage? Your experience may be interesting for SSD-longevity statistics.  Can you keep track of time (how often srm is executed) and quantity (size of the deleted files)?

Comment: I don't understand. If I wipe log files every shutdown will I destroy my ssd drive???